# Duvida em array n linhas x 3 colunas

Tags: javascript

Estou em duvida em matriz JS, onde preciso incluir um valor dentro da primeira posição de cada item consecutivamente. 
Código JS:

```
m_aluno = new Array ();   
    if(w_cont < w_alun)//w_cont é para não passar do valor informado and w_alun é o valor informado;
    {
        for(a=0; a < w_alun; a++)
            for(c=0; c < w_cole; c++)
                for(s=0; s < w_sala; s++)
                    for(m=0; m < w_mate; m++){
                        m_aluno[a][c]= w_nome;
                        m_aluno[a][s]= w_nome;
                        m_aluno[a][m]= w_nome;
                    }
                    w_cont++;   
    }
```

Ou seja: Eu quero incluir na primeira posição de cada um o nome digitado!
O nome digitado esta em `w_nome;`

Basicamente eu gostaria de adicionar na posição 0 do array o nome inserido mas pelo visto em JS não é possível, pois acho que JS não faz suporte; Pois a estrutura dela ficaria:

```
m_aluno[c][s][m]= "nome";
```

Comment: Acho que você vai ter que explicar um pouco melhor a estrutura desse _array_, pois ou está faltando índice (e não é 5x3), ou você está usando loops pra coisa que deveria ser estática (ou ambos). Teria como descrever um exemplo de como a array deveria ficar no final, pra dois alunos, por exemplo?

Comment: acho que a explicação deu na mesma, não sabemos quantos w_cole cada aluno pode ter, etc. Melhor dar um exemplo prático da array preenchida, e não do que está imaginando (ajude-nos a te ajudar). Iria bem explicar de onde vem as outras informações também, pois não dá pra saber o que w_cole é (se é array, se é um número, se é uma string)

Comment: Mesmo após a edição, não melhorou muito... Você pode dar nome aos bois? Por exemplo: o que esta matriz conterá, exatamente? Nomes, notas, dados cadastrais? Como ela está estruturada (o que representam as linhas e as colunas)?

Comment: Exemplos com dados concretos ajudariam mais que teorias. As teorias são baseadas na forma como você enxerga o problema. Os dados concretos ajudariam a apresentar uma solução pro problema, independente da forma que vc está conseguindo ver. Procure por um exemplo exatamente do que vc quer (e explique o que é cada um dos dados).

Comment: Tudo indica que você só precisa de um loop, e dentro de cada posição da array um objeto (e não mais arrays). Mas precisaria postar as informações que o Bacco e o Rui pediram pra gente poder afirmar qualquer coisa.

Comment: O título da pergunta não convida quem estiver lendo a página principal a abrir a pergunta e ver qual o problema. É o típico exemplo de título pobre, tente caprichar nisso também.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma matriz, em JavaScript, pode ser simulada através de Arrays aninhados.

O que é chamado de *linha* ou *coluna* é meramente simbólico e abstrato; eu, especificamente, gosto de pensar nas linhas como sendo as posições do Array pai:

```
var minhaMatriz = [
    linha0, // ainda indefinida!
    linha1 // ainda indefinida!
];
```

Mas cada linha (para que obtenhamos uma *matriz*) ***é*** um Array em si, onde cada posição representa uma célula, cuja definição é o cruzamento de uma linha com uma coluna. Dessa maneira, podemos dizer que "*as linhas possuem as colunas*" (segundo a maneira que eu gosto de pensar):

```
var minhaMatriz = [
    [ "L0 C0", "L0 C1", "L0 C2" ],
    [ "L1 C0", "L1 C1", "L1 C2" ]
];
```

Com isso, teremos uma matriz 2x3, ou seja, 2 linhas por 3 colunas.

Como o JavaScript é uma linguagem com tipagem dinâmica, além de o conteúdo (valor) de cada célula estar inteiramente aberto à sua escolha, não precisamos nem mesmo definir o tipo; basta iterar sobre a matriz para setar ou modificar o valor de cada coluna.

Para iterar sobre a matriz, basta iterar sobre as chamadas *linhas*, e, dentro dessa iteração, iterar também sobre as chamadas *colunas*. No exemplo abaixo, o índice `i` denota a linha atual, e o índice `j` denota a coluna atual:

```
// Troca o valor de todas as células para o inteiro 0:
for(var i = 0; i < minhaMatriz.length; i++){        // Para cada linha (índice "i")
    for(var j = 0; j < minhaMatriz[i].length; j++){ // Para cada coluna (índice "j")
        minhaMatriz[i][j] = 0;                      // Troca o valor da célula da linha "i", coluna "j".
    }
}
```

Assim, para percorrer apenas a primeira coluna de uma matriz, só precisamos de um único loop:

```
// Troca o valor de cada célula da primeira coluna para 0:
for(var i = 0; i < minhaMatriz.length; i++){
    minhaMatriz[i][0] = 0; // Troca o valor da célula da linha "i", coluna 0.
}
```

---

## Tamanho variável

Até aqui, criamos uma matriz 2D (matriz bidimensional, ou seja, possui as dimensões *altura*, que corresponde ao número de linhas, e *largura*, que corresponde ao número de colunas) conceitualmente estática, no sentido de ter sido declarada já com os dados.

Ela também poderia ter sido declarada sem nenhuma linha:

```
var minhaMatriz = [];
```

Independentemente de como ela foi declarada, porém, podemos tanto **editar os dados dentro dela** (como já demonstrado), podemos também aplicar operações sobre o tamanho dela.

### Inserção de linhas

Como já dito anteriormente, a matriz é um Array de linhas, e as linhas são programadas como Arrays de células. Dessa maneira, para adicionarmos linhas, basta inserir um novo Array de células no Array matriz, através do método nativo `push(elemento)` do array. **Obs**.: este método sempre adiciona o "`elemento`" **ao final** do Array, portanto, no exemplo abaixo, a nova linha será a última:

```
minhaMatriz.push(
    [ "Nova linha C0", "Nova linha C1", "Nova linha C2" ]
);
```

### Remoção e/ou inserção de linhas em índices arbitrários

Da mesma forma, há uma função nativa que remove* elementos do Array: `splice(indice, quantidade)`. **Obs**.: este método remove, a partir da posição denotada por "`indice`", um número "`quantidade`" de elementos. Para removermos o último elemento, por exemplo, podemos fazer:

```
// Remove, da última posição da matriz (minhaMatriz.length - 1), um (1) único elemento:
minhaMatriz.splice(minhaMatriz.length - 1, 1);
```

- Na realidade, o `splice()` também adiciona elementos! Ele pode ser usado de maneira a inserir linhas na nossa matriz em posições arbitrárias! Exemplo:

  minhaMatriz.splice(1, 0,
      [ "C0", "C1", "C2" ]
  );

---

## Exemplo interativo

Para resumir, apresento um pequeno programa que insere e remove linhas em posições arbitrárias. (Provavelmente só funcionará nos browsers mais recentes!)

```js
// Declaramos uma matriz com pelo menos uma linha, para que nosso exemplo saiba quantas
// colunas pretendemos utilizar:
var m = [
    [ "Olá", "Stack Overflow", "em Português!" ]
];

// Localizamos os elementos declarados no HTML com os quais interagiremos:
var inputIdx = document.getElementById("inputIdx");
var botaoAdd = document.getElementById("botaoAdd");
var botaoRem = document.getElementById("botaoRem");
var pTabelas = document.getElementById("pTabelas");

// Criamos uma caixa para cada coluna (elementos dinâmicos, declarados 'on the run'):
var inputs = [];
for(var i = 0; i < m[0].length; i++){
    inputs.push(_new("input", document.getElementById("spanInputs")));
}

_print(); // Mostramos como está nossa tabela inicialmente.



// Ao clicar o botão de adicionar, criamos uma nova linha no índice específicado:
botaoAdd.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var novaLinha = [];
    for(var i in inputs) novaLinha.push(inputs[i].value);
    
    m.splice(+inputIdx.value, 0, novaLinha);
    // OBS.: o "+" aqui é uma forma rápida de converter para inteiro!
    
    _print(); // Mostra como ficou nossa matriz.
});



// Ao clicar o botão de remover, removemos a linha do índice especificado:
botaoRem.addEventListener("click", function(){
    m.splice(+inputIdx.value, 1);
    // OBS.: o "+" aqui é uma forma rápida de converter para inteiro!
    
    _print(); // Mostra como ficou nossa matriz.
});



// Imprime a matriz como uma tabela HTML dinâmica:
function _print(){
    // Retira a visualização antiga:
    while(pTabelas.firstChild) pTabelas.removeChild(pTabelas.firstChild);
    
    var table = _new("table", pTabelas);
    
    // Cria a linha de título:
    var titleRow = _new("tr", table);
    _new("th", titleRow);
    for(var j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++){
        var titleCell = _new("th", titleRow);
        titleCell.innerHTML = j;
    }
    
    // Para cada linha da matriz, cria uma linha na tabela HTML:
    for(var i = 0; i < m.length; i++){
        var row = _new("tr", table);
        
        // Em cada linha, insere uma coluna de título:
        var titleCell = _new("th", row);
        titleCell.innerHTML = i;
        
        // Para cada coluna da matriz, insere uma coluna HTML:
        for(var j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++){
            var cell = _new("td", row);
            cell.innerHTML = m[i][j];
        }
    }
}







// Função de comodidade para criar e exibir elementos de maneira dinâmica. IGNORE-A! :)
function _new(tag,pai){
    var el = document.createElement(tag); // Cria elemento pedido.
    pai.appendChild(el);                  // Insere o elemento no pai.
    return el;                            // Retorna o elemento para manipulações posteriores.
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: 1px solid black; padding: 2px 15px; }
input { width: 75px; }
```

```html
<p>
    Linha a inserir: <span id="spanInputs"></span>
    <br />
</p>
<p>
    Índice: <input id="inputIdx" type="number" value="0" />
    <button id="botaoAdd">Adicionar no índice</button>
    <button id="botaoRem">Remover do índice</button>
    <br />
</p>
<p id="pTabelas"></p>
```

---

## Conclusão

Para fazer a matriz N x 3 (N linhas de 3 colunas) que você precisa, basta pensar que a coluna indexada por j=0 é o colégio, a coluna j=1 é a sala, e a coluna j=2 é o que você chama de *mate* (matéria / disciplina?).

Assim, não faz sentido aumentar o número de dimensões da matriz (por exemplo, programá-la N x M x O x P). O problema deve estar mais localizado na representação (modelagem) do conhecimento do seu negócio, do que na linguagem JavaScript em si.

Caso precise de mais ajuda em JS, um primeiro passo é sempre verificar a documentação da "classe"

Comment: Vamos torcer pra ser só isso ;)

Comment: Isso que eu precisava @RuiPimentel' foi dificil me explicar mas consegui chegar ao que eu precisava!

Comment: Ou seja, para declarar a matriz nx3 var minhaMatriz=[[,,]];

Comment: Comente se a resposta bateu com o que você precisava!

Comment: A resposta bateu com o que eu precisava, mas como eu deveria montar o n x 3? Não consegui decifrar como!

Comment: Se a ideia é tornar dinâmico o tamanho da matriz (e **não** aumentar o número de dimensões), inserindo e excluindo elementos, dá uma olhada nas novas alterações :D